# Storing variables in HTML5 localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm currently in development of a minesweeper game and I want to store the value of a '`noWins`' variable into local storage once the game is won (I have a boolean called `wonGame` which is set to true when the game is won).

How can I do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461884/local-storage-html5-demo-with-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store data in localStorage, you use the `setItem()` function. This function takes two parameters, the item key and a value.

```
if(wonGame == true){
  localStorage.setItem('noWins', 'value');
}
```

In response to your comment,

local storage stores values as strings, therefore the value has to be converted to a number using parseInt. The first value for noWins would be set to 0

so the new code should be

```
//set the initial value of noWins to 0
localStorage.setItem('noWins' , 0)
if (wonGame === true){
var winning = parseInt(localstorage.getItem("noWins");
//increment value
localStorage.setItem("winning", winning++)
}
```

Note that "winning" is just a variable I created

Comment: How would I increment this? Would it be something along the lines of : localStorage.getItem('noWins') = number(localStorage.getItem('noWins')) +1